# How can I convert UTC time from GNGGA sentence

Tags: python

I try to use datetime.strptime (timestr,'%H%M%S%.%S') for converting GNGGA UTC time, but i receive the following error : error: redefinition of group name 'S' as group 4; was group 3

How to fix this issue ?

Thanks

THe GNGGA sentence for UTC is as follows hhmmss.ss, so i use to convert with %H%M%S.%S but there is an error

Comment: Use the correct letter to indicate the fraction of a second.